# Image pre-processing for convolutional neural network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to make mushroom classifier with tensorflow using CNN.
But, I wonder about image data pre-processing.
Should I remove background of picture as black color or just use raw picture?

Also, if any pre-processing step before cnn what I do, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>The question is a little bit too broad, but I'll give you a hint.</sup>

> Should I remove background of picture as black color or just use raw picture?

If you can do this, you can achieve higher accuracy with data augmentation, because you can generate training images with various backgrounds, thus help generalization.

Note however that by just removing the background the neural network will likely "get used" to the black background, so you would need to translate your test images as well, which in turn needs image segmentation.

Since image segmentation is even harder than classification, the background is usually left unchanged.

> Also, if any pre-processing step before CNN what I do, please let me know.

The one pre-processing step that works consistently for all image related tasks is zero-centering: compute the mean value across the training set and use that value to zero-center the images. Be careful not to use test images in computing the mean.